# Query not working unless I change the Date format to Automatic

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query, date

[image]
[image]

Query works fine if I change Hudson F to Automatic, if I change it to date it stops working. I need to view F as date and have the query work

`=QUERY(Hudson2000!1:6634, "SELECT A, B, C, D, F, G WHERE F >= "&A2&" AND F <= "&B2)`

Answer (score 0):

The problem occurs because Google Sheet cells and QUERY data type are the same.

Instead of A2 and F2 use `TEXT(A2,"YYYY-MM-DD")` and `TEXT(F2,"YYYY-MM-DD")` and enclosed inside `date 'xxxx'` where xxxx is the place for the date.

The resulting formula is the following:

`=QUERY(Hudson2000!1:6634, "SELECT A, B, C, D, F, G WHERE F >= date '"&TEXT(A2,"YYYY-MM-DD")&"' AND F <= date '"&TEXT(F2,"YYYY-MM-DD")&"'")`

Comment: Thank you for your help but for some reason its still now working. Can i share the file with you somehow to take a closer look?

Comment: I got it working with your query, just had to change the F2 to B2. Thank you very much for all your help.